# How to clone public submodule in "Github Actions"

Tags: github, git-submodules, github-actions

*Reason for this Q&A-Style question: It took me a few hours to get this to run because I had some typos and thought the solution is more complicated. If I would have found a tutorial like this on google or Stackoverflow I would have checked for typos.*

**Git Repository Setup:**

- **Private repository `A`** - name: `repoA`
- with **submodule `B` (public repository)** - name: `repoB`

**Goal:**

- I want to run a `gradle build` in `repository A > Github Actions`

**Github Action Workflow**

```
name: Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
```

**Problem:**

- The `actions/checkout@v1` step fails to access the submodule

**.gitmodules**

```
[submodule "library"]
    path = library
    url = git@github.com:organization/repoB.git
```

**Github Actions Step `Build with Gradle` error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':repoA:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':repoA:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :repoBSubmodule1.
     Required by:
         project :repoA
```

**What I tried:**

---

1. Add `with: submodules: true` to `actions/checkout@v1`

```
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      with: 
        submodules: true
```

**Github Actions Step `Run actions/checkout@v1` error**

```
(...)
git submodule sync
git -c http.https://github.com.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" submodule update --init --force
Submodule 'repoB' (git@github.com:organization/repoB.git) registered for path 'repoB'
Cloning into '/home/runner/work/repoA/repoA/repoB'...
Host key verification failed.
##[error]fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

---

2. Use 3rd party Github Actions like `textbook/git-checkout-submodule-action@2.0.0`

**Run textbook/git-checkout-submodule-action@2.00 error:**

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /github/workspace)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
##[error]Docker run failed with exit code 128
```

---

3. Add a *personal access token* to the `actions/checkout`

   - The token was generated from a github user which has access to that repository
   - The repoA is owned by an organization
   - the token has full `repo` permissions

```
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      with: 
        submodules: true
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_REPO_TOKEN }}
```

***Run actions/checkout@v1 error:***

```
git submodule sync
git -c http.https://github.com.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" submodule update --init --force
Submodule 'repoB' (git@github.com:organization/repoB.git) registered for path 'repoB'
Cloning into '/home/runner/work/repoA/repoA/repoB'...
Host key verification failed.
##[error]fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I.e. with the that token which has access to both, repoA and repoB I was not even able to checkout the parent repoA.

Answer (score 14):

Now you can use actions/checkout@v2

As https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-submodules said:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout root
- name: Checkout submodules # checkout rest
  shell: bash
  run: |
    # If your submodules are configured to use SSH instead of HTTPS please uncomment the following line
    # git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf "git@github.com:"
    auth_header="$(git config --local --get http.https://github.com/.extraheader)"
    git submodule sync --recursive
    git -c "http.extraheader=$auth_header" -c protocol.version=2 submodule update --init --force --recursive --depth=1
```

Comment: Should there be a - at the start of both top lines here? Trying to get this to work on windows.

Comment: @Macke Sorry, my mistake. These are two steps and each step needs a `-`

Comment: That action can do submodules without additional scripting.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [actions/checkout@v2](https://github.com/actions/checkout) without additional scripting. I used this on Mac, Linux and Windows. Meanwhile v3 is available:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    submodules: true
```

For [recursive submodules](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/34) (where a submodule requires another submodule), use

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    submodules: recursive
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the submodule URL from the SSH to the HTTPS format fixed it:

***.gitmodules***

```
[submodule "repoB"]
    path = repoB
#Before:
    url = git@github.com:organization/repoB.git
# After:
    url = https://github.com/organization/repoB.git
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows based runner the following worked:
Created a bot-user, generated Access Token, included the user into private (submodules) repos and added this in actions.yml:

```
  - name: Checkout submodules using a PAT
    shell: bash
    run: |
      git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp url | while read url; do
      git config --file=.gitmodules $(echo "$url" | sed -E "s/git@github.com:|https:\/\/github.com\//https:\/\/${{ secrets.GHACTIONS_PAT }}:${{ secrets.GHACTIONS_PAT }}@github.com\//")
      done
      git submodule sync
      git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This block alone just gave me authentication errors like
`fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Hiran Chaudhuri Not sure why this happens for you, have you provided the personal access token (PAT) in you repository secrets as I did with GHACTIONS_PAT ?

Comment: I resolved it by using actions/checkout@v2 with submodules: true